# How do you recall the last (n-th?) passed argument of the previous command you used with bash?

Tags: bash

Often times I issue different commands on the same file. For example:

```
$ youtube-dl aB54c4p0eo #I made this video id up on the spot
$ mv aB54c4p0eo.flv kittens.flv
$ vlc kittens.flv
$ rm kittens.flv
```

Is there a way to reuse arguments from the previous command in the current so that I don't have to rewrite it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`alt-.` is certainly nice, but if you happen to already know which numbered argument you want, you can be faster: `!:n` is the `n`th argument of the previous command.

It's often helpful to combine this with magic space. To enable that, put in your .inputrc `Space: magic-space`. With that enabled, when you type space after `!:2`, it will be immediately expanded to its value instead of waiting for you to hit enter. Saves you from accidentally grabbing the wrong argument.

Answer (score 10):

In bash you can use the shortcut `Alt` + `.`.
Hitting it once, will give you the last argument. Hitting it more will cycle through your last arguments.

Answer (score 5):

In bash, the designator for the "last word on previous command line" is `!!$` :

```
$ echo hello world
hello world
$ echo goodbye !!$
echo goodbye world # this is bash echoing actual cmd line before execution
goodbye world
```

You can also use the "caret syntax" to replace the *initial* part of the command line; this comes handy if you want to execute several commands on the same file:

```
file file.dat
^file^ls -l^ #gives `ls -l file.dat`
^ls -l^stat # gives `stat file.dat`
```

There are many more possibilities; see "History substitution" in the [bash(1) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/bash) for details.

Comment: That caret syntax is actually slower than pressing up arrow and editing the command line yourself...

Comment: `!!$` can be written `!$` too.

Answer (score 4):

In bash, you can also use $_ for the last command line argument of the last command you typed:

```
$ youtube-dl aB54c4p0eo #I made this video id up on the spot
$ mv aB54c4p0eo.flv kittens.flv
$ vlc kittens.flv
$ rm kittens.flv
```

becomes:

```
$ youtube-dl aB54c4p0eo #I made this video id up on the spot
$ mv $_ kittens.flv
$ vlc $_
$ rm $_
```

Answer (score 0):

One relatively slow way is recalling the previous command with **<kbd>↑</kbd>** and replacing the previous command with the newer one.

Comment: I'm hoping for something faster :)