# Bash: Access parameter passed to last command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, parameter

This is a situation I often find myself in:

```
mkdir /Some/really/long/path/to/a/directory/
cd /Some/really/long/path/to/a/directory/
```

I know that ideally you would `cd /Some/...etc.../a/` and then `mkdir directory`, but I've often performed `mkdir` first and then had to `cd` to the end of the same lengthy file path I just created.

Short of doing...

```
var="/Some/...etc.../a/"
mkdir $var/directory; cd $var
```

...which is even worse, is there some way to reuse the parameter passed to the *previous* command? I'm aware of course of tab completion, but in a series of nested directories with similar names this doesn't always help that much. Ideally, I'm hoping for a shortcut like `$#` or `$@`.

Failing this, the next best time-saving solution would be equally appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a one-liner that allows me to create a directory and move into it at the same time?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9123/23408)  ... or [How do you recall the last (n-th?) passed argument of the previous command you used with bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3357/23408)

Comment: But a good duplicate I think in its more general sense (for _any_ previously passed argument) where I ask: "is there some way to reuse the parameter passed to the previous command?"

Comment: OK, I added one like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash (and some other shells, like zsh), you can use `$_`, which contains the last argument to the previous command:

```
mkdir /path/to/file
cd "$_"
```

Comment: And of course also in `ksh`.

Answer (score 3):

There are previous answers that suggest you to use `$_` and `!$`. While this works, I find it quite dangerous as they are not expanded and you cannot see their value before pressing enter and executing the command. Imagine using `rm $_` without being sure what you're going to delete!

If you're using bash (probably with readlines's emacs mode, which is the default), I suggest you to press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, release it, and then press <kbd>.</kbd>.

This shortcut recalls the last argument from the last executed command. So writing `cd <ESC> <.>` will bring you your long path/file.

The hotkey <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (pressed simultaneously) works in the same way.

If you're using bash vi mode instead of the default's emacs mode, you can simulate this behaviour with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> if you alter your `~\.inputrc` file with:

```
set keymap vi-insert

$if mode=vi
    "\e.": yank-last-arg
$endif
```

Answer (score 2):

When working interactively, you can use history expansion for this:

```
mkdir /Some/really/long/path/to/a/directory/
cd !$
```

There are loads of variants to this which allow you to access other parameters from the previous command or any other command in your history. See [Bash, insert last used argument of current command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183355/bash-insert-last-used-argument-of-current-command/) for details...